# Is there a convention for writing Python function names in plain text?

Tags: python, text

Eg the Ruby community would describe an instance or class method `foo` of a class `klass` as 'klass#foo' or 'klass.foo' when writing in plain text (or just as '#foo' or '.foo' for brevity) which can help to avoid ambiguity.

Are there comparable conventions when writing about Python?

Comment: You can write `klass.foo` in python, to refer to method `.foo` of class `klass`, or to refer to function `foo` of module `klass`. I don't know if that answer your question?

Comment: Check for examples in the documentation…? E.g.: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects. `klass.method` is used throughout…

Comment: I think the reasoning would be the same for Python community as well. Actually except C++ community who would write it as `klass::foo`, I think the rest would do the same.

Comment: Being pedantic, it seems this question is most generally about the names of "callable attributes in namespaces" (which is even more general and pythonic than "methods in classes") rather than *function* names.

Comment: @Stef Is there then any distinction between the way you write class methods and instance methods?

Comment: @Arepo Not in the python syntax, no. But the convention is to use lowercase with underscores for almost every name in python, with the notable exception of classes which are written with capitals and no underscore. So it's probably `my_module.my_function` and `MyClass.my_method`.

Comment: @Arepo Although again, there are exceptions; builtin classes `list`, `dict` and `set` are all in lowercase.